# What is JishoPlus in iCloud storage?

Tags: icloud

I have storage for something called JishoPlus in my iCloud storage breakdown. I can't find anything definitive about it online. I know how to delete it (and I will), but what is it from?

[image: JishoPlus]

Answer (score 1):

From the name it seems like some kind of Japanese-English Dictionary app. Did you install something like that?

Comment: Some other dictionaries, but nothing Japanese

Comment: I see. Jisho is Japanese for Dictionary. Probably related